# Oracle: Pasar datos de una tabla a otra, y eliminarla automáticamente de la tabla origen

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

tengo una duda sobre como armar el funcionamiento de un procedure. La función del procedure es que los registros de la tabla **USUARIO** que tenga como ***estado*** "0" se pasen a la tabla **AUDITORIA_USER** y después se eliminen automáticamente de la tabla origen que sería **USUARIO**, donde sólo estarían los registros de usuarios que tenga como ***estado*** "1".

[image: Estos son mis tablas:]

Este es mi modelo de procedure, pero me salta error en el *if* :

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE AUDITORIA_USER(
    a_ceula_id  IN   number,
    a_id_audt   OUT  number,
    a_id_user   OUT number,
    a_nombre    OUT varchar2,
    a_fecha_reg    OUT date,
    a_estado    OUT number
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        --ACA PASO DATOS DE UNA TABLA A OTRA--
        if a_cedula_id=usuario.cedula_id and usuario.estado=0 then
            update auditoria_user ac set ac.id_user = (select oc.id_user from usuario oc where oc.ceula_id = ac.cedula_id)
                where ac.cedula_id in (select oc.cedula_id from usuario where oc.cedula_id = ac.cedula_id);
            update auditoria_user ac set ac.nombre = (select oc.nombre from usuario oc where oc.ceula_id = ac.cedula_id)
                where ac.cedula_id in (select oc.cedula_id from usuario where oc.cedula_id = ac.cedula_id);
            update auditoria_user ac set ac.fecha_reg = (select oc.fecha_reg from usuario oc where oc.ceula_id = ac.cedula_id)
                where ac.cedula_id in (select oc.cedula_id from usuario where oc.cedula_id = ac.cedula_id);
            update auditoria_user ac set ac.cedula_id = (select oc.cedula_id from usuario oc where oc.ceula_id = ac.cedula_id)
                where ac.cedula_id in (select oc.cedula_id from usuario where oc.cedula_id = ac.cedula_id);
            update auditoria_user ac set ac.estado = (select oc.estado from usuario oc where oc.ceula_id = ac.cedula_id)
                where ac.cedula_id in (select oc.cedula_id from usuario where oc.cedula_id = ac.cedula_id);
        end if;
        --ACA ELIMINO LOS REGISTROS DE LA TABLA BASE--
        delete from usuario where a_cedula_id=usuario.cedula_id and usuario.estado=0;    
    END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> create or replace PROCEDURE AUDITORIA_USER 
>      IS
>      -- no necesitamos pasar ningun parametro si la condicion es que todos los usuarios sean igual a cero en la tabla usuario
>      BEGIN
>      -- insertamos en la tabla destino AUDITORIA_USER la condicion de los usuarios que tengan estado 0
>      Insert into AUDITORIA_USER >(id_audt,id_user,nombre,cedula_id,fecha_reg,estado) select seq_auditoria.nextval,id_user,nombre,cedula_id,fecha_reg,estado from usuario where estado=0;
>      -- borramos los datos en la tabla origen
>      delete usuario where estado=0;
>
> END;

recuerda que el seq_auditoria.nextval es la secuencia debes creala en el mismo esquema donde ejecutas ese procedimiento!

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad sí me había complicado mucho, y creo que por las puras, me diste una buena idea para seguir con mis ejemplos.

Comment: De nada hermano! Estamos para ayudarnos!